# I need to update customer information in one SQL Server database from another 

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, quickbooks

I am new to databases, and I am looking for some help. We have a custom app that was written that keeps its data in a SQL Server database. We also have a POS system which is based upon QuickBooks Point Of Sale. We are purchasing a product called QODBC, which gives us an ODBS compliant interface to QBPOS.

The SQL Server database has a table called `customerinfo` and has 15 columns of information we are interested in out of 70 total.

They are:

`id, txtfname, txtlname, txtemployer, txtphone, email, txtaddress, txtcity, txtstate, txtzip, IDENTIFICATIONType, IDENTIFICATIONumber, IDState, IDENTIFICATIONExpiry & dtpBirth`.

These columns need to be imported into the ODBC-accessable QBPOS, which has columns that are named differently, with QB preceeding all the above names (example the SQL Server column is `id` so the QBPOS column is `QBid`). What

we would like to do is import on a regular schedule (say every minute or so) the data that we need into QBPOS. First, other than the every minute or so import schedule, is it possible to do it via an icon we could just put on the desktop and only do it when we need to? Also, would we be able to just update changed data from the SQL Server database for existing customers?

I thank you all in advance for any help you can offer!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow.  The answer to all of your questions is "yes, it's possible"; however, you'll get more help if you can ask questions in the format of "here's my setup.  I tried this.  What else should I try?"

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, it is much simpler for data to be pulled rather than pushed.

This means that it is preferable for you to set up a schedule on the QBPOS system, that queries the MS SQL Server to collect the data you need.  I do not, however, know anything about QBPos and can't comment on how to do this, or even if it is possible.

The alternative is to push one record at a time into QBPOS from SQL Server.  This is certainly possible, but I would expect it to be slow...

1. Create a LOGIN on the QBPOS server that your automated process will use
2. Create the same LOGIN (with the same password) on the MS SQL Server
3. Create a LINKED SERVER on the MS SQL Server that connects to QBPOS
4. Create a STORED PROCEDURE that INSERTS records into the appropriate QBPOS table
5. Go to the MS SQL Server's Agent Scheduler and create a new job that fires every minute
6. Set that job to execute your STORED PROCEDURE

(Although your code may look like it's pushing a whole set of data in one go, if you profile the SQL Server you'd see that it's firing off many individual Insert/Update/Delete commands.  This is why it is the slower mechanism of the two.)

To update the QBPOS server with just the *changes* to the SQL Server, you need to do something like...
- Record when each change happened (deletes as well as inserts and updates)
- Store in the QBPOS server the timestamp of the last change it received
- Check that value in your SQL Server stored procedure to determine what changes to push

Note: There is a difference between "what has been pushed" and "what has been received" as it is possible for the QBPOS database to be restored from back-up, etc.  This means that the "last received data" value *must* be stored in the QBPOS database.

This answer is deliberately fairly high level as scripting the exact solution to all of this would take a whole lot of space.  If there are any terms or concepts you're unfamiliar with, I'd recommend searching them out in Books Online or Google, and seeing what you can manage yourself, and having a little bit of a play.  It's very important in these kinds of things to know what your doing and why, rather than just copy explicit instructions from some-one else.

Comment: Well, this all needs to happen outside QBPOS, it doesn't have any facilities to do any of this, that is why we are going to purchase the third party ODBC driver. Since all of this needs to happen outside, Is this something I could just have an icon on the desktop which when clicked would run the sql statement that I will have to write?

Comment: @user1113091 - Only if you have written an App or something that runs a query on your SQL Server.  You can then replace the Agent Scheduled Job with the app that you run to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: @user1113091 - If you have access to multiple servers where you can test the use of LINKED servers and write a test version of this set-up, I'd do it.  Test and understand the proposed solution, before buying components to make it work.

Comment: Although I agree with most of Dems solution, the 'push' could be done SET based too IMHO. Simply fetch the entire current situation from QBPOS into a temporary table, compare with the content of the customer table in your database and then apply the differences as needed in one go. (do you even want to do deletes on the QBPOS side?).
Going by this [this][1] linked server should work but seems to require a 'special' version... try before you buy (if possible) =)


  [1]: http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=10668&nav=0,58,66

Comment: @deroby - If you do `INSERT INTO [linked-server].[db].[schema].[table] SELECT * FROM source` and then look in the profiler, you'll see that they QUERY is set based, but that SQL Server will actually fire off one INSERT for each record.

Comment: Ah, duh... didn't know that. Is that a limitation of ODBC in general ? And is it only for IUD or for SELECT too? I've ran into some very slow queries on DB2 in the past (via DTS at the time) where doing a bunch of JOINS directly on the AS400 seemed to take forever. Downloading the (raw) content first and do the join in MSSQL was much faster even though I was copying way more data than actually needed.. That said, those fetches were as fast as the network allowed, so doing a fetch first, comparing on MSSQL and only updating as needed still seems like a good approach. Thx for the info.

Comment: @deroby - Data can't be pushed as a data set, only pulled.  So a SELECT will come through as a SET.  It gets more tricky if their is a JOIN involved which spans the two databases.  You'll either see "pull the remote table here, then join" or you'll see one query for every row in the local table.  The choice is the optimisers.  If both tables are remote, the join is done remotely.

Comment: In that case my rant on 'that lousy DB2-driver' remains standing =) All data was remote and it took ages to run the join. When one of the AS400 guys 'simulated' it in PL\SQL (or-something?) directly in the 'console' of the AS400 it was fast though, so it obviously was not an issue of hardware or volumes...  strange things and probably not relevant here nor nowadays (supra was in early 2000's).